# Wordpress multiple theme one with ads and one without ads

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

### Is it possible to have a wordpress blog with two themes.

```
(1) One I need to keep Google adsense ads
(2) Other without Google adsense
I need these two themes in two different subdomains. 
example : 
www.blog.myWebsite.com => **can have adsense**
www.mob.myWebsite.com => **Should not have adsense** 
I want to use www.mob.myWebsite.com for android webView

I mean to say , the same blog post with two different theme.
I will be posting only in one post and I want the content in two themes. 
example : I want in the bellow two pages should have the same content with two themes
    www.blog.myWebsite.com/aaaa/firstpost
    www.mob.myWebsite.com/aaaa/firstpost
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Multiple Themes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/) plugin which allows you to select different themes of each page.

or

Since you already have a sub domain, you can install another wordpress installation on each of the subdomains.

Comment: I mean to say , the same blog post with two different theme 
 I will be posting only in one post and I want the content in two themes . 
example : I want in the bellow two pages should have the same content 
www.blog.myWebsite.com/aaaa/firstpost
www.mob.myWebsite.com/aaaa/firstpost

Comment: What do YOU mean by themes? The design and color? (HTML/CSS?)